# Upgrading PHP on an ARM CPU

Tags: php, macos, upgrade

I just changed my MacBook for an ARM CPU and I am trying to make my projects work.

I need PHP 7.4 for one of them.

Homebrew is not supposed to work on arm for now but you can still install it in `/opt/homebrew` which I did.

`brew install php@7.4` worked fine and /`opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/7.2.14/bin/php -v` gives me the right version of PHP.

I add `PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/7.2.14/bin:${PATH}"` in my `~/.bash_profile` and made `source ~/.bash_profile`.

But `php -v` still gives me 7.3 version, any idea how to use 7.4 by default?